# Let $A=\{(x,x) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 0 \le x \le 1\}.$ Find the $2-$dimensional Lebesgue measure $m^\ast(A).$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $A=\{(x,x) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 0 \le x \le 1\}.$ Find the $2-$dimensional Lebesgue measure $m^\ast(A).$

I found this question here without answers and I cannot solve it. I have a bit trouble finding a cover for $A$. I tried something like $I_k=(-\frac{\varepsilon}{k}, 1+\frac{\varepsilon}{k})$, but this doesn't work. Is there some general method to find covers for sets or how should I do this? I feel like the measure should be zero since the line that this set is doesn't have any area, but I need to find some cover with what I can use here.

Comment: It's $0 \le x \le 1$?

Comment: Yes. Now the title should be correct also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. For each $1\leq i\leq n$ define $I_n^i=[\frac{i-1}{n}, \frac{i}{n}]^2$. Then your set is contained in the union $\cup_{i=1}^n I_n^i$, and so its measure is bounded by $\sum_{i=1}^n m(I_n^i)=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n}$. Since $n$ is arbitrary, this proves that the measure is $0$.

Comment: How did you get $[\frac{i-1}{n}, \frac{i}{n}]^2$? I'm a bit confused with the indexes here. The index $n$ here seems to be representing the width and height of the box?

Comment: @UniQGat The sets I defined are $[0, \frac{1}{n}]^2, [\frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n}]^2, [\frac{2}{n}, \frac{3}{n}]^2,...,[\frac{n-1}{n}, 1]^2$. It should be more clear now.

Comment: @UniQGat Sorry, I just noticed I called the sets $I_n$, without mentioning the index $i$. I fixed it now. Call the sets $I_n^i$.

Answer (score 0):

You hit a subset of the diagonal because of $(x,x)$. The diagonal is a null set since it's one dimensional (in a two dimensional space). So the messure is $0$.

Edit: If you want to cover it take $n$ squares of side length $1/n$. They have an area of $1/n$.

Comment: This is what I concluded also, but this needs to be shown by covering the diagonal and then using the properties of the outer measure that $m^\ast(A) \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \ell(I_k)$, where $\{I_k\}_k$ covers the set.

Comment: @UniQGat Sure, I added a cover.